# Recyclerview with different row layouts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my recyclerview , I current use 4 different layouts for rows. I would like to add 8 more but before doing that , I wanted to ask you guys if having 12 different type of row layouts in a recyclerview is gonna lead to performance issues

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. It is sometimes a judgment call but as a general rule, the more complexity and nesting you put in your layout, the more time it needs to render that layout and eventually the performance will be decreased.

Android Studio has special built in tool to measure the time for rendering your view called `Hierarchy Viewer`, you can use it to measure on your design